# Characterization of morphisms of finite Tor-dimension by the hypertor functor

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, derived-categories

I am trying to have a concrete understanding of morphisms of finite Tor-dimension between arbitrary schemes.
In Hartshorne’s book Residues and Duality,a morphism of schemes $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is said to have finite Tor-dimension if the inverse image functor $f^*:Mod(O_Y)\rightarrow Mod(O_X)$ has finite cohomological dimension.
I would like to ask whether this definition can be characterized by the statement that a morphism of schemes $f:X\rightarrow Y$ has finite Tor-dimension if and only if there is an integer $n\geq 0$ such that the hypertor functor $Tor_i^{f^{-1}O_Y}(\mathcal F^{.},O_X)$ vanishes for every $\mathcal F^{.}\in D(f^{-1}O_Y)$ and every integer $i>n$.
If yes, then we can work with the stalks of the hypertor functor to check whether a morphism of schemes has finite Tor-dimension.
I just managed to show that the vanishing of higher Hypertor functors is equivalent to Quillen’s definition of morphisms of finite Tor-dimension, which requires the $f^{-1}O_Y$-module $O_X$ to have finite Tor-dimension.
So now the question is, how to show that Hartshorne’s definition of morphisms of finite Tor-dimension is equivalent to Quillen’s definition?